# May one learn / talk after Yishtabach when waiting for the Chazan to start Birchos Krias Shema?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, hefsek-interruption

I know you can't talk during פסוקי דזמרה, and certainly not during ברכות קריאת שמע. What about between them? And if not talking, what about דברי תורה?

Answer (score 5):

[Mishna Berura 54:3:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=165&hilite=) says that one may do any Dvar Mitzva between Yishtabach and Yotzer, however no talking is allowed. Thus one may look into a Sefer during that time, however one can not give a Shiur then.

Comment: Looking it up there, it sounds like one may talk for the sake of a dvar mitzvah. If so, isn't learning Torah a mitzvah?

Comment: Looking into a Sefer is not the same as speaking.

Comment: Correct. But he mentions speaking to collect tzedoka, which is speaking for the sake of a mitzva.

Comment: He mentions giving Tzedaka, not collecting. Although perhaps one can collect without talking.

Comment: The רמ"א write "ומזה נתפשט מה שנהגו בהרה מקומות לברך חולה או לקבל בבית הכנסת שיעשה לו דין בין ישתבח ליוצר דכל זה מקרי לצרך מצוה" and that definitely involves talking.

Comment: I looked up the פסקי תשובות (on מ"ב) and I think it supports how I'm reading it, because he says that in spite of this משנה ברורה (not because of it) we don't speak at all (except for certain responses to the ציבור, ע"ש.) It says there: אך כבר נהגו כל ישראל שלא לעשות שום הפסק בין ישתבח ליוצר ואף לא לצרי מצוה דרבים וצדקה וכדומה,... and footnote 11 there says ערוה"ש סעי' ד', וכן בכה"ח סקי"א דיש ליזהר ולהחמיר שלא להפסיק בדיבור בין ישתבח ליוצר אפילו לצור מצוה...

Comment: So what is your answer? To learn or not to learn? Or to learn w/o mouthing the words?

Comment: Isn't giving a Shiur a Mitzva?